# 403 Error Crawling Pages

Tags: sitemap, web-crawlers, 403-forbidden

I am receiving more than 6000 errors in Google Webmaster Tools. It is showing "access denied"; can anyone please help me out with resolving this?

Comment: You're going to have to tell us a lot more then that.

Comment: google webmaster tools is showing 403 errors although the robots.txt is fine and site is running good but it is not showing on google. i am losing ranking day by day

Answer (score 1):

On GWT, Health > Fetch as Google, and try to fetch one of the pages marked as "Access Denied". The result comes almost immediately.

It can be that your server is not well configured and for whatever reason it returned 403 when Google tried to crawl those pages. Fetching as Google will force the crawler to re-visit the page and if it returns 200 OK, the URL will be submitted to index. If it is returning 403 only to Google, you will need to figure out what is the problem with your server.

Comment: i have tried with fetch as Google. It is showing still error. I think the server is not allowing google bot i dont know why